# Display ul list above div on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display ul list above div but only on **mobile**. What is the best way to do that?
Here is a simple code:

```
<div>
    <div>
      <p>
        This is a content!       
      </p>
    </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
  </ul>
```

Ideal scenario on mobile would be like this:

```
<div>

  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
  </ul>

    <div>
      <p>
        This is a content!       
      </p>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: on desktop it is this list on bottom or somehow arranged left or right to the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and use the [order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) inside a media query to flip the flex items.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper>div {
    order: 2;
  }
  .wrapper>ul {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <p>
      This is a content!
    </p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. very much:-)